# Find an equation for the plane through the origin and the point Q(1, 1, 1) that is perpendicular on the ground.

Tags: vectors

I'm a little bit confused about the point Q, is it perpendicular on the ground or is the plane through it? I tried to answer it like this: the equation for the plane is n.PoP = 0
where n is the normal vector which equals <1, 1, 1> and Po is a point in the plane which equals (0, 0, 0) and the equation becomes: x + y + z = 0. Is this the correct answer? if not then what is the correct one? and I also want to find the answer of "then find an equation for the line of intersection between the plane and the ground surface. Assume the ground surface is a regular plane." here's what I think the answer is: we find a vector from the cross product between the normal vectors of the plane we found and the ground surface (but what is the equation for the ground surface??) then we find a point by solving the two planes equations and the result: x = xo + at ; y = yo + bt ; z = zo + ct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Write the general formula of the plane:
$$\pi:ax+by+cz+d=0 $$
Now take advantage of the condition you have:

$(0,0,0)\in \pi \implies d=0$

$(1,1,1) \in \pi \implies a+b+c=0$

Now, since the plain is perpendicular to the ground (e.g. the plane with equation $z=0$), the dot product of the normal vectors must be $0$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a\\b\\c
\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix}=0 \implies c=0$$
Hence, you have $a+b=0$, namely $a=-b$. The plain you're searching is;
$$\pi: x-y=0 $$

Answer (score 0):

The plane we are looking for is $ax + by + cz + d = 0$.

Since we want it to be orthogonal to the ground $z=0$, we must have $\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = 0$

Furthermore, since it passes through the points you gave, we must also have

$\begin{cases}a\cdot0+b\cdot0+c\cdot 0 + d= 0\\a + b + c + d = 0\end{cases}$

Can you find $a,b,c,d$?